# Find the maximum of three sinusoidal voltages at any point?

Tags: voltage, transistors, diodes

Given three sinusoidal input voltages, I need to design a circuit to output the highest voltage, without using opamps. I honestly have no idea where to start, so would just appreciate any hints or reading material. All I want is a pointer to the right direction.

The maximum voltage output needs to decay with a time constant of one second.

How can I go about building this circuit?

Comment: Probably use some kind of peak hold. What is the name of the class you are taking (assuming this is for a class). The reason I ask is to guide any possible answer in the right direction. Also, please include the full text of the problem in your question, and let us know what you have tried so far. This will encourage people to help, because it looks like you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output will be which ever signal is the highest - 1 diode drop (use small schottkys for low drop ~0.3V)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgu9TN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Hm, thank you. This works perfectly. How was the 10kΩ value calculated? Does it just need to be very large?

Comment: The value isn't important, it's just there to provide a little pull down so that the output doesn't float, you could probably leave it out and it wouldn't make much difference

Comment: Ah I see. Actually I needed the max value to decay at a particular time constant so the value of the resistor combined with value of a capacitor ended up being important for me.

Comment: This will show the maximum positive (w.r.t. ground) not the absolute max of 3

Comment: Yes, if the Absolute value is needed then things get really complicated (well, without resorting to opamps anyway)

Comment: In my understanding you need peak detector for your requirement. The circuit above specified is ok but you need to add the capacitor parallel to the resistor.The peak voltage is stored in the capacitor and to discharge the charge in the capacitor you need that resistor. Select the resistor and capacitor according to your time requirement.